# BERT NER detect multiple words as one entity

Tags: nlp, bert-language-model, simpletransformers

I' using bert to train custom ner model.i'm using simpletransformer pacakge. I have 2 custom entity - place, other

In dataset as for word column I have multiple words for particular label in row eg

Sentence_id |words         |labels
17.         |united states |place
17.         |south Africa. |place
Eg  have sentence
Hi I'm XYZ from United states

While predicting model is predicting output for each word. I want model to take 2 words for predicting ner. Eg instead of united it should use united states as entity

Is there any way or configuration that where we can pass numerical of words(n-grams) that model should take

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with simpletransformers, but it looks like it only provides one label per token. What you can do in that case is label the first token of an entity `B-[LABEL]` and any following tokens `I-[LABEL]`. This is known as [IOB Tagging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inside%E2%80%93outside%E2%80%93beginning_(tagging)).

It's kind of weird that you have to do that manually, though. For most NER systems that should be automatic. You can see an example of automatically handling multi-word entities in [the spaCy course](https://course.spacy.io/en/).